# Reshape 3D numpy array to 2D

Tags: python, numpy

I use an LSTM AutoEncoder model and I want to transform the output prediction (numpy array of 3 dimensions) to a DataFrame

```
series_predicted = autoencoder.predict(np.reshape(series.values, (series.shape[0], timesteps, series.shape[1])))
series_predicted.shape
(3296, 1, 268)
```

How should I resolve the "timesteps" dimension in order to get back to 2 dimensions and transform it to a DataFrame?

`df_predicted = pd.DataFrame(series_predicted, column=series.column)`

Comment: is [numpy.squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: Exactly, I solved with np.squeeze(series_predicted, axis=(1,))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dimension with `size=1` you can use `np.squeeze`. However, this function does not work for dimensions with `size>1`. You can use `np.reshape` (if it is this you are looking for). Here is a toy example:

```
a = np.random.rand(4,2,3)
a = a.reshape((4*2,3))
```